# batchscript concatenate filename string through for loops

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to do simple filename string concatenation through loop but somehow it doesnt' work. Been trying to search for it in stack overflow but the solution does not realy work.

here is my code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set str=
for /r %%i in (*) do (
    set str=%str%'%%i'
)
echo %str%
endlocal
```

My file Directory is C:\dir. Files insides are just file1.txt, file2.txt.

I am hoping for this output for `%str%` : `'C:\dir\file1.txt','C:\dir\file2.txt'` but my output turns out to be this: `%str%` : `'C:\dir\file2.txt'`. It only outputs the last file in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
set str=!str!,'%%i'
```

then

```
echo %str:~1%
```

See any number of SO articles about `delayed expansion` for the reason.

Each individual item is added to the list after a comma, so the `:~1` uses batch-substringing to `echo` the string, starting at the 1th character (where it starts at the 0th character)